# i am trying to make the actor "player" show on screen (along with the other actors) and add controls to it

Tags: python, pygame, controls, pgzero

```
import pgzero, pygame

#music, sprites and background

music.play("temp.mp3")
x = 0
y = 0

WIDTH = 850
HEIGHT = 425
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

title = Actor('title.png')      #calling sprites and saying their pos
title.pos = 400, 212
cont = Actor('cont.png')
cont.pos = 470, 300
player = Actor('ship.png')
player.pos = 100, 56
foe = Actor('foe.png')
foe.pos = 200, 112

def draw():
    screen.clear()
screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
title.draw()
cont.draw()
player.draw()
foe.draw()
vel = 5



#controls
screen.update()

while True:
    player.pos = x, y
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit(); sys.exit()
            main = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                print('left')
                x -= vel
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                print('right')
                x += vel
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                print('up')
                y += vel
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                print('down')
                y -= vel

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                print('left stop')
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                print('right stop')
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                print('up stop')
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                print('down stop')
            if event.key == ord('q'):
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
                main = False
screen.update()
```

I have tried to get it to work but i keep getting various errors the one I'm getting at the moment its: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'blit'
I'm new to coding i find it quite interesting but i dont seem to be getting the hang of it haha. Hopefully you can help my issue :D Thanks!

Comment: You cannot mix an application loop and [pygame Zero](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction.html). You have to use the event hooks like [`on_key_down`](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/hooks.html#buttons-and-keys). The event handling in [Pygame Zero](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news) is completely different. Please correct the [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html)

Comment: could you clarify for me? Where should i fix the indentation? which line? What should i indent it to? should i indent it out further or further back? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) in your code is incorrect after `screen.clear()`. You have to delete the complete `while True:`-loop. This code will not work with [Pygame Zero](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction.html). It is a [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) application and event loop. Pygame Zero is based on Pygame but it is not the same. You cannot use Pygame zero, but the event handling of Pygame. Note `draw` is continuously invoked in the background. `draw` is the "application loop".

A working example may look as follows:

```py
import pgzrun
import pygame

WIDTH = 850
HEIGHT = 425

title = Actor('title.png')      #calling sprites and saying their pos
title.pos = 400, 212
cont = Actor('cont.png')
cont.pos = 470, 300
player = Actor('ship.png')
player.pos = 100, 56
foe = Actor('foe.png')
foe.pos = 200, 112
vel = 5

music.play("temp.mp3")

def draw():
    screen.clear()
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    title.draw()
    cont.draw()
    player.draw()
    foe.draw()

def update():
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    x, y = player.pos
    x += (keys[pygame.K_d] - keys[pygame.K_a]) * vel
    y += (keys[pygame.K_s] - keys[pygame.K_w]) * vel
    player.pos = x, y

pgzrun.go()
```

Comment: Thankyou! Its alot more compact! And it works! Thanks!